# Any way to pull information from this website

Tags: java, android, web

I wanted to know how to pull the menus dynamically from this website without having to hardcode the links to each month's menu every time the month changes. I'm trying to implement this on an android application, so code in Java would be very helpful

This is the website where I want to pull the menus from ([Link](http://www.schoolnutritionandfitness.com/index.php?page=menus&sm=6&sy=2013&sid=0608121745464795))

Can someone provide me with an example of how one would do this?

Comment: I don't think it would be hard to get the month and year from `Calendar` class =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this url:

http://www.schoolnutritionandfitness.com/index.php?page=menus&sm=6&sy=2013&sid=0608121745464795

sm param seems to be month
sy obiouslly year

Use jsoup to get the data you want from the dates you need making up url.

Answering your comment: refer to http://jsoup.org/ then you can make more specific questions further!!

Comment: Could you maybe teach me how one would go on doing this? .__.